# Javascript: check for minimum string length

Tags: javascript, html, char

I have a problem:

I have a website and a section where you can adress a letter to me. I want a character minimum in this letter. I know how I can say that there must be a character when there is no character:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function chkFormular () {
    if (document.contact.message.value == ""){
        alert(unescape("Please enter a message."));
        document.contact.message.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can add a character minimum with 50 characters like the example above?

Thanks for help

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't work. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: I found out why it doesn't work. It must be 'if (document.contact.message.value.length < 50'. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, that what I wrote in the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, you can check the length of a string using the `length` attribute. So - to check for a minimum of 50 characters, you need to use:

```
if (document.contact.message.value.length < 50) {
    alert(unescape("Please enter at least 50 characters."));
    document.contact.message.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Change it to 'if (document.contact.message.value.length < 50'. Then you get the check